# Room SQLite inheritance

Tags: android, sqlite, inheritance, android-room

I'd like to represent in the database the relation between **magazines** and **persons**.
One magazine could be created by more than one person, and a person could create more than one magazine.

Given that a person could be a writer, photographer, illustrator... at the same time, how could I represent it in the database knowing that each person type contains the same fields, that is, no specific fields are needed?

I think in the following relation:

```
Person table
+------+--------+
| id   |  name  |
+------+--------+
|    1 | name1  |
|    2 | name2  |
+------+--------+
                          
Magazine table    
+------+--------+
| id   | title  |
+------+--------+
|    1 | title1 | 
|    2 | title2 | 
+------+--------+

PersonMagazineRelation table
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| person_id | magazine_id | type        |
+------+--------+---------+-------------+
|     1     |      1      | writer      |
|     1     |      1      | photographer|
+------+----+-------------+-------------+
```

The *PersonMagazineRelation* table has the three fields as the primary key because the same person could contribute to a magazine as a writer and as a photographer.

I would like to query a Magazine that contains:

```
Magazine(title, listOfWriters, listOfPhotographers)
```

Where the *listOfWriters* and *listOfPhotographers* contains a list of names.

Does this make sense of having a table with three primary keys?
Is there any better approach? Maybe creating a new table for each type of person or is it ok with the above approach?

Comment: You say *Does this make sense?* Asking for *`Magazine(title, personName, listOfWriters, listOfPhotograpers)`* what is personName? The writer, illustrator?????. Asking for `Magazine(title, listOfWriters, listOfPhotograpers)` would make sense.

Comment: Oh yes @MikeT, I update the question. The person name should be inside the listOfWriters and listOfPhotographers.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this make sense of having a table with three primary keys? Is there any better approach?

Yes, **However** handling the 3 way mapping is a little difficult/out of the norm. The issue is that Room expects what I term as Complete Objects via the `@Relation` annotation. That is it gets ALL related objects as such using `@Relation` for a 3 way (`@Embedded` for Magazine, `@Relation` for Person and `@Relation` for Type) would get all people as a list and all types as a list.

If not using `@Realtion` and just `@Embedded` (magazine) then you get an object for each combination (Cartesian product).

Here's a demo that at least allows you to get the lists so grouped.

First, I'd suggest an additional table for Type (better to call it something else such as Role) table.

So 4 tables; Magazine, Person, PersonMagazineRelation and Type.

I'd also suggest using unique column names so instead of id magazineId, PersonId and so on. (eliminates chance for ambiguities and more complicated SQL using aliases).

So 4 Entities (Magazine is left to last):-

**Person**

```
@Entity
data class Person(
    @PrimaryKey
    val personId: Long? = null,
    val personName: String
)
```

**Type**

```
@Entity
data class Type(
    @PrimaryKey
    val typeId: Long? = null,
    val typeName: String
)
```

**PersonMagazineRelation**

```
@Entity(
    primaryKeys = ["personRelationId","magazineRelationId","typeRelationId"],
    indices = [
        Index("magazineRelationId"),
        Index("typeRelationId")
              ],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(entity = Person::class,parentColumns = ["personId"],childColumns = ["personRelationId"]),
        ForeignKey(entity = Magazine::class,parentColumns = ["magazineId"],childColumns = ["magazineRelationId"]),
        ForeignKey(entity = Type::class,parentColumns = ["typeId"],childColumns = ["typeRelationId"])
    ]
)
data class PersonMagazineRelation(
    val personRelationId: Long,
    val magazineRelationId: Long,
    val typeRelationId: Long
)
```

- ForeignKey's aren't mandatory but enforces referential integrity (parents must exist)
- extra indicies aren't mandatory (Room warns if not indexes)

Finally **Magazine** noting that this is not a data class so as to allow a function that will retrieve the list's according to type.

```
@Entity
class Magazine(
    @PrimaryKey
    val magazineId: Long? = null,
    val magazineTitle: String
) {
        fun getPeopleByType(dao: AllDao, typeId: Long): List<PersonType> {
            return dao.getMagazinesPerSonByMagazineAndType(this.magazineId!!,typeId)
        }
}
```

Now some POJO's (i.e. not tables but allow extract of joined data)

**PersonType** (allows a person with the type to be extracted)

```
data class PersonType(
    @Embedded
    val person: Person,
    @Embedded
    val type: Type
)
```

**MagazinePersonType** (allow magazine,person and type to be extracted, demo's 3 @Embedded's)

```
data class MagazinePersonType(
    @Embedded
    var magazine: Magazine,
    @Embedded
    val PersonType: PersonType
)
```

Now some Dao's (see comments) in **AllDao**

```
@Dao
/* Not an interface to allow functions */
abstract class AllDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(person: Person): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(magazine: Magazine): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(type: Type): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(personMagazineRelation: PersonMagazineRelation): Long

    /* not of much use */
    @Query("SELECT * FROM personmagazinerelation ORDER BY magazineRelationId, typeRelationId")
    abstract fun getAll(): List<PersonMagazineRelation>

    /* Get all Magazines with Person and their Type not really required but demo's 3 @Embedded's*/
    @Query("SELECT * FROM personmagazinerelation " +
            "JOIN magazine ON magazineRelationId = magazineId  " +
            "JOIN person ON personRelationId = personId " +
            "JOIN type ON typeRelationId = typeId")
    abstract fun getPersonTypeForAMagazine(): List<MagazinePersonType>

    /* THIS IS THE QUERY FOR GETTING LIST of PEOPLE BY TYPE */
    @Query("SELECT * FROM personmagazinerelation " +
            "JOIN person ON personRelationId = personId " +
            "JOIN type ON typeRelationId = typeId " +
            "WHERE typeId = :typeId AND magazineRelationId = :magazineId")
    abstract fun getMagazinesPerSonByMagazineAndType(magazineId: Long, typeId: Long): List<PersonType>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM magazine")
    abstract fun getMagazines(): List<Magazine>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM type")
    abstract fun getTypes(): List<Type>

    /* Used to make demo re-runnable */
    @Query("DELETE FROM personmagazinerelation")
    abstract fun clearPMR(): Int
    @Query("DELETE FROM magazine")
    abstract fun  clearMagazines(): Int
    @Query("DELETE FROM person")
    abstract fun clearPeople(): Int
    @Query("DELETE FROM type")
    abstract fun clearTypes(): Int


    fun clearAll() {
        clearPMR()
        clearMagazines()
        clearPeople()
        clearTypes()
    }
}
```

Putting the Room stuff all together i.e. the **`@Database`** class namely **TheDatabase**

```
@Database(
    entities = [Person::class,Type::class,Magazine::class,PersonMagazineRelation::class],
    version = 1
)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"magazine.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

**The Demo code**

In an activity **MainActivity** is the following code that adds some data (3 types, 4 people and 4 magazines) and then populates the PersonMagazineRelation table with various combinations (Mag4 has nothing, Mag3 has all possible combinations i.e. all 4 people have all 3 types).

Then there are two extracts. The first uses the 4 tables joined. The second extracts all the magazines and the uses the Magazine's `getPeopleByType` function to get the people per type for each type.

So :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()
        dao.clearAll()

        var t1 = dao.insert(Type(typeName = "Writer"))
        var t2 = dao.insert(Type(typeName = "Photographer"))
        var t3 = dao.insert(Type(typeName = "Illustrator"))
        var p1 = dao.insert(Person(personName = "Fred"))
        var p2 = dao.insert(Person(personName = "Mary"))
        var p3 = dao.insert(Person(personName = "Jane"))
        var p4 = dao.insert(Person(personName = "Tom"))
        var m1 = dao.insert(Magazine(magazineTitle = "Mag1"))
        var m2 = dao.insert(Magazine(magazineTitle = "Mag2"))
        var m3 = dao.insert(Magazine(magazineTitle = "Mag3"))
        var m4 = dao.insert(Magazine(magazineTitle = "Mag4"))

        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p1,magazineRelationId = m1,typeRelationId = t1))
        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p1,magazineRelationId = m1,typeRelationId = t2))
        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p3,magazineRelationId = m1,typeRelationId = t2))
        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p3,magazineRelationId = m1,typeRelationId = t3))

        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p4,magazineRelationId = m2,typeRelationId = t2))
        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p4,magazineRelationId = m2,typeRelationId = t3))
        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p2,magazineRelationId = m2,typeRelationId = t3))
        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p3, magazineRelationId = m2,typeRelationId = t1))

        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p1,magazineRelationId = m3,typeRelationId = t1))
        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p1,magazineRelationId = m3,typeRelationId = t2))
        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p1,magazineRelationId = m3,typeRelationId = t3))
        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p2,magazineRelationId = m3,typeRelationId = t1))
        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p2,magazineRelationId = m3,typeRelationId = t2))
        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p2,magazineRelationId = m3,typeRelationId = t3))
        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p3,magazineRelationId = m3,typeRelationId = t1))
        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p3,magazineRelationId = m3,typeRelationId = t2))
        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p3,magazineRelationId = m3,typeRelationId = t3))
        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p4,magazineRelationId = m3,typeRelationId = t1))
        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p4,magazineRelationId = m3,typeRelationId = t2))
        dao.insert(PersonMagazineRelation(personRelationId = p4,magazineRelationId = m3,typeRelationId = t3))

        var mpt = dao.getPersonTypeForAMagazine()
        for(m: MagazinePersonType in mpt) {
            Log.d("MPTINFO","Magazine is ${m.magazine.magazineTitle} Person is ${m.PersonType.person.personName} ${m.PersonType.type.typeName} ")
        }

        val TAG = "MAGINFO"
        var types = dao.getTypes()

        for (m: Magazine in dao.getMagazines()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Magazine is ${m.magazineTitle} ID is ${m.magazineId}")
            for (t: Type in types) {
                Log.d(TAG,"\tType is ${t.typeName} ID is ${t.typeId}")
                for(pt: PersonType in m.getPeopleByType(dao,t.typeId!!)) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"\t\tPerson is ${pt.person.personName}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**RESULT**

The first query (cartesian product) using MagazinePersonType (all embedded) :-

```
2021-08-25 08:16:59.884 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag1 Person is Fred Writer 
2021-08-25 08:16:59.884 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag1 Person is Fred Photographer 
2021-08-25 08:16:59.884 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag1 Person is Jane Photographer 
2021-08-25 08:16:59.884 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag1 Person is Jane Illustrator 
2021-08-25 08:16:59.884 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag2 Person is Tom Photographer 
2021-08-25 08:16:59.884 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag2 Person is Tom Illustrator 
2021-08-25 08:16:59.885 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag2 Person is Mary Illustrator 
2021-08-25 08:16:59.885 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag2 Person is Jane Writer 
2021-08-25 08:16:59.885 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag3 Person is Fred Writer 
2021-08-25 08:16:59.885 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag3 Person is Fred Photographer 
2021-08-25 08:16:59.885 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag3 Person is Fred Illustrator 
2021-08-25 08:16:59.885 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag3 Person is Mary Writer 
2021-08-25 08:16:59.885 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag3 Person is Mary Photographer 
2021-08-25 08:16:59.885 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag3 Person is Mary Illustrator 
2021-08-25 08:16:59.885 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag3 Person is Jane Writer 
2021-08-25 08:16:59.885 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag3 Person is Jane Photographer 
2021-08-25 08:16:59.885 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag3 Person is Jane Illustrator 
2021-08-25 08:16:59.886 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag3 Person is Tom Writer 
2021-08-25 08:16:59.886 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag3 Person is Tom Photographer 
2021-08-25 08:16:59.886 D/MPTINFO: Magazine is Mag3 Person is Tom Illustrator
```

The second extract, the Magazines with their List's (extracted as a function/method of the Magazine Object when/as required) :-

```
2021-08-25 08:16:59.889 D/MAGINFO: Magazine is Mag1 ID is 1
2021-08-25 08:16:59.889 D/MAGINFO:  Type is Writer ID is 1
2021-08-25 08:16:59.890 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Fred
2021-08-25 08:16:59.890 D/MAGINFO:  Type is Photographer ID is 2
2021-08-25 08:16:59.891 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Fred
2021-08-25 08:16:59.892 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Jane
2021-08-25 08:16:59.892 D/MAGINFO:  Type is Illustrator ID is 3
2021-08-25 08:16:59.893 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Jane
2021-08-25 08:16:59.893 D/MAGINFO: Magazine is Mag2 ID is 2
2021-08-25 08:16:59.893 D/MAGINFO:  Type is Writer ID is 1
2021-08-25 08:16:59.894 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Jane
2021-08-25 08:16:59.894 D/MAGINFO:  Type is Photographer ID is 2
2021-08-25 08:16:59.895 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Tom
2021-08-25 08:16:59.895 D/MAGINFO:  Type is Illustrator ID is 3
2021-08-25 08:16:59.896 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Tom
2021-08-25 08:16:59.896 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Mary
2021-08-25 08:16:59.896 D/MAGINFO: Magazine is Mag3 ID is 3
2021-08-25 08:16:59.896 D/MAGINFO:  Type is Writer ID is 1
2021-08-25 08:16:59.898 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Fred
2021-08-25 08:16:59.898 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Mary
2021-08-25 08:16:59.898 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Jane
2021-08-25 08:16:59.898 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Tom
2021-08-25 08:16:59.898 D/MAGINFO:  Type is Photographer ID is 2
2021-08-25 08:16:59.900 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Fred
2021-08-25 08:16:59.900 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Mary
2021-08-25 08:16:59.900 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Jane
2021-08-25 08:16:59.900 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Tom
2021-08-25 08:16:59.900 D/MAGINFO:  Type is Illustrator ID is 3
2021-08-25 08:16:59.902 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Fred
2021-08-25 08:16:59.902 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Mary
2021-08-25 08:16:59.902 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Jane
2021-08-25 08:16:59.902 D/MAGINFO:      Person is Tom
2021-08-25 08:16:59.902 D/MAGINFO: Magazine is Mag4 ID is 4
2021-08-25 08:16:59.902 D/MAGINFO:  Type is Writer ID is 1
2021-08-25 08:16:59.904 D/MAGINFO:  Type is Photographer ID is 2
2021-08-25 08:16:59.905 D/MAGINFO:  Type is Illustrator ID is 3
```